# ArcMap - Date field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, date

I am trying to append some data to an existing enterprise geodatabase feature class, the data I am trying to append has a date field where some entries are in correct, eg instead of 03/19/1983 they have 03/19/198, this is throwing the append off as the enterprise geodatabase won't allow the append if the date is entered incorrectly.

Is there a field calculator snippet that can find these instances so I would be able to manually correct them?

There are like 20,000 records that I need to QC.

Comment: Are you able to use arcpy?

Comment: In what format is the data that `03/19/198` is permitted?  This isn't about the EGDB so much as it is about the source format.

Comment: As said by @Vince if 03/19/198 is permitted you probably don't have a date field but more likely a text field if that the case you may just check for string less than 10 character (this of course will only find date with missing character, not other error...)

Comment: no, it isnt permitted in the target geodatabase feature class it will kick up an invalid date entry

Comment: @Vince @ J.R - sorry dont seem to be able edit my previous post to put these on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach.  Create a **new integer-type field**, and populate it using this **code block**:

```
from datetime import datetime

min_date = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
max_date = datetime.today()


def check_valid_date_str(s):
    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return min_date <= dt <= max_date
```

and this **expression**:

```
check_valid_date_str(!YOUR_DATE_FIELD_NAME!)
```

This tries to parse the value into a date object.  If it fails then it didn't match the expected format.  If it succeeds, it makes sure it's within the expected range, which you can edit as necessary.

Then use select by attributes on that new field to highlight the issues.

This assumes your "date" field actually contains strings, which it seems to as pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: Thats perfect - thank you Mike!